# Myloader command: Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysqldump, mysql-5.6, percona-tools, mysqlbinlog

I took the backup of mysql database using mydumper command:

> mydumper -B mydb -o /backup/oct3 -s 500000 -c -m -S /tmp/mysql.sock -u
>   root -p password@123 -v 3

Now, I am restoring mysql database backup with the myloader command:

> myloader -d /backup/oct3 -S /tmp/mysql.sock -u root -p password@123 -v
>   3

ERROR:

> CRITICAL **: Error restoring mydb.tabe1 from file mydb.table1.sql.gz:
>   Table 'mydb.table1' doesn't exist
>   ** Message: Thread 2 shutting down

I believe the table should be created while restoring the database.

But I could not figure out what I missed. The mydumper version is 0.6.2.

My.cnf file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2308M
innodb_data_home_dir = /database
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1G;ibdata2:1G;
innodb_log_file_size=1073741824
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC
innodb_file_per_table = 0
```

The dumped .gz files are from MySQL 5.5 and I am restoring to MySQL 5.6.

Does it matter of version incompatibility?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

problem is you backed up your databases using mydumper with -m or --no-schemas option, so the database create commands were not backed up.

So on restore you are not able to re-create the database tables prior to myloader reimporting data.

Comment: Thanks p4guru. I took schema backup with following command and loaded schema before backup with myloader.

# mysqldump -u root -p --no-data dbname > /backup/rcmwf.schema.sql